# Github-pages deploy, firebase request Error: "Missing or insufficient permissions." in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, github-pages

I'm using firebase in my React app.
I've got a problem when my app is deployed to the web. (via github-pages).
The strange part here is that it's telling me that I don't have permissions while my firebase rules are set to allow all incoming requests (see image).

Does anyone know how to solve this issue / know why this is happening?

When I press my "Get Tokens" button I request data from the usersData collection with the following query:

```
const {user, logout, deleteSignedUser} = UserAuth();

async function getDataFromUser() {
        // we get the documentId of the user with:
        // docId = user.uid; The uid of the user is the same as the uid of the document in the users' collection.
        const docRef = doc(firestoreDB, 'usersData', user.uid).withConverter(tokensConverter);
        // we get the document
        const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
        // print the document to the console
        console.log(docSnap.data());

        // we get the data from the document and set it to the states
        setTokens(docSnap.data().tokens); // we set the tokens to the state
        setUsername(docSnap.data().username); // we set the username to the state
    }

    const [tokens, setTokens] = useState(undefined);
    const [username, setUsername] = useState(undefined);

return(
<>
    {tokens && <h4>Tokens available: {tokens}</h4>}
    {username && <h4>Username: {username}</h4>}

    <Button onClick={getDataFromUser} 
       variant='primary' 
       className="col-6">
       Get Tokens
    </Button>
</>
);
```

My AuthContext:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
    signInWithEmailAndPassword,
    signOut,
    onAuthStateChanged,
    sendPasswordResetEmail,
    reauthenticateWithCredential,
    deleteUser,
    EmailAuthProvider,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from '../services/firebase';

const UserContext = createContext(undefined);

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({});

    // sign up a new user with email and password
    const createUser = (email, password) => {
        return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    };

    // login an existing with email and password
    const signIn = (email, password) =>  {
        return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    }

    // reset password
    const resetPassword = (email) => {
        return sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email);
    }

    // logout the user
    const logout = () => {
        return signOut(auth)
    }

    // delete the user
    const deleteSignedUser = async (password) => {
        const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(auth.currentUser.email, password)
        const result = await reauthenticateWithCredential(auth.currentUser, credential)

        await deleteUser(result.user)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
            console.log(currentUser);
            setUser(currentUser);
        });
        return () => {
            unsubscribe();
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ createUser, user, logout, signIn, resetPassword, deleteSignedUser}}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    );
};

export const UserAuth = () => {
    return useContext(UserContext);
};
```

[My firebase rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2MPW.png)

[What it should do (this is on localhost)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz08s.png)

[Error when deployed on the web (github-pages)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E63ts.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had started this project as a copy from my first project made with react and firebase.

I had edited my project id in the files you can see listed below, but forgot to change this id in my .env.production.local file.

So while I was testing with my database on localhost I was using the correct id from the .env.development.local file, but the moment I published my project with github-pages it tried using the other file with the wrong id which of course doesn't work.

**Short version: Make sure your .env files have the right data / are filled in for both local and public deploy.**

[.env files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W2a4.png)

[A field for my project id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYesV.png)

[Example Firebase config where I was filling in my project id from the .env file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkZQd.png)